# How to stop Jmeter script automatically after 3 hours using scripts

Tags: selenium, jmeter

How to stop Jmeter script automatically after 3 hours using scripts.I don't want to use default schedule time which available in Thread group.Need some automation scripts(Eg: Selenium) automation like that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 shells in bin folder:

- shutdown.sh waits for current running samplers to end before stopping test
- stopTest.sh  interrupts sampler running when called to immediately stop test

Comment: DIRNAME=`dirname $0`

java -cp ${DIRNAME}/ApacheJMeter.jar org.apache.jmeter.util.ShutdownClient Shutdown "$@"

Comment: getting like this what i need to do here, as i'm new to jmeter.

Comment: When I run test in windows in GUI mode these commands (.cmd) didn't stop the test

Comment: how to stop the test after 3 hours automatically by using scripts

Comment: you need to run in non gui mode (add -n) . In a shell you would start the test, pause for 3h and then call the shutdown.

Comment: ./jmeter -n -t \absolute_path\mytest.jmx -l \absolute_path\mytest_results.jtl

how to puase the script for 3hr here ?

how to call shutdown here?

Comment: can any one give the code to stop the jmeter script through scripts(by selenium or any other)

Comment: I gave all elements to do what you want but you need to work a bit to assemble it.

Comment: google the doc but need some few steps on "In a shell you would start the test, pause for 3h"